# Excel Add-In sharing memory between Class Libraries

Tags: .net, excel, com, add-in, interprocess

Environment : C#, .NET 3.5 , Windows 7 64, Excel 2007, Visual Studio 2010

I have a VS2010 with 3 projects :

**Projet « Business » :** A class library with a  global static variable

```
List<BusinessClass>
```

**Project « Add-In » :** Extensibility Shared Add-in and the Add-In class:

```
[GuidAttribute("A9E83593-395F-4112-855D-A68C5088151F"), ProgId("eFrontCubeAddIn.CubeAddIn")]
public class CubeAddIn : Object, Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2, ICustomTaskPaneConsumer {…}
```

Excel will call OnConnection and I will use the Excel object(ExcelApp = (Excel.Application)application;) to interact. All the interactions within "Add-In" are done via COM (InvokeMember).
The `List<BusinessClass>` is created and filled from "Add-In"

**Project « Formulas » :** Class Library. One UDF Excel specific formula. Methods are built using the following model and registered using [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]RegisterFunction(Type type)…

```
[Guid("5268ABE2-9B09-439d-BE97-2EA60E103EF6")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyFunctions {
public double MyUdfFunction(double number1, double number2) {
{
return number1 * number2;
}
```

My problem is very simple to explain:  I have a Ribbon and a Custom Pane in the project « Add In » filling the `List<BusinessClass>.`
When the Excel User enters ‘=MyUdfFunction(6 ;7)’ in a cell, my method in « Formulas » is called. 
As it comes from a different process (from Excel) the UDF has no access to  « Business » instances and `List<BusinessClass>` is unreachable.

The UDF could be sometimes called more than 500.000 times 
For speed reasons, I dont want to insert a VBA script calling my UDF in the loop.
For speed reasons, I dont want to use Shared memory, Named pipes, WCF or other artifacts.
Dont want to use the UDF services (cant use Sharepoint server).

I know that when u are in a different process you cant use data from other processes.

**Any idea to give "Formulas" direct access to "Business" instance ? Like having ALL 3 projects in the same process...**

Thanks in advance
Jean Marie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Formulas" project is an Excel Automation add-in. Add-in Express allows you to have a COM add-in and XLL add-in in the same assembly; they will load into the same AppDomain, check [HowTo: Create a COM add-in, XLL UDF and RTD server in one assembly](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/03/24/addin-xll-rtd-one-assembly/). More precisely, an Automation add-in can be implemented in the same assembly, too but you cannot have the Automation add-in loaded in the same AppDomain in **all** situations.

Also note another blog: [Invoking a COM add-in from an Excel XLL add-in: advanced sample](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/11/invoke-excel-addin-xll/).

Answer (score 1):

For speed you need to be using the XLL interface where possible, particularly for UDFs. I suggest you look at using Addin Express (costs) or Excel DNA (free), both of which give you .NET interfaces to Excel using both Interop-COM and XLL in-process.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I have contacted Add-In Express to see if their model solves my problem.